# Oracle Apex query which needs to compare two attributes from different time within two tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle-apex

- [Required task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqTBZ.jpg)
- [Table details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYD91.jpg)

In this query (first link), I tried to compare amounts by means of logical operation, but I'm not sure is it the correct method or not.

If it is not the professional way, I would appreciate your help.

```
P.s Oracle DBMS 

SELECT D.DELIVERERID,D.NAME
FROM DELIVERERS D
WHERE DELIVERERID IN (SELECT DELIVERERID 
                       FROM PENALTIES P1
                       WHERE DATA>=TO_DATE('01/01/1980','DD/MM/YYYY' )AND 
                             DATA<=TO_DATE('31/12/1980','DD/MM/YYYY' ) 
                         AND P1.AMOUNT>AMOUNT IN  (SELECT DISTINCT AMOUNT 
                                                   FROM PENALTIES 
                                                   WHERE DATA>=TO_DATE('01/01/1981','DD/MM/YYYY') AND 
                                                   DATA<=TO_DATE('31/12/1981','DD/MM/YYYY' )
                                                   GROUP BY AMOUNT ));
```

Comment: Did you test your query ? If so did you get errors ?

Comment: Constantly, I received an error which was saying I didn't use parenthesis correctely

Comment: so... you debug... That error probably included a line number. Hint: the syntax "P1.AMOUNT>AMOUNT IN  (..." is not valid oracle syntax.

Comment: Posting a reproducible case will greatly increase you're chances of getting an answer (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). No jpg -few people want to spend 30 minutes creating a reproducible case based on a screenshot, that is something the poster of the question can do himself

Comment: Actually , that's my question , what would be the correct possible syntax ?

Comment: Happy to give it a go if you  create that reproducible case for me.